# Tcl/Tk: combobox - auto complete

Tags: combobox, tcl, tk-toolkit

I need auto completion in my `combobox`. In the following code, if I type `T`, only `Tennessee` and `Texas` should be displayed while typing `Tex` should completely fill it with `Texas`.

```tcl
ttk::combobox .c -values [list Alabama Alaska Arizona Arkansas \
          California Colorado Tennessee Texas]
pack .c -padx 10 -pady 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at:
http://wiki.tcl.tk/15780

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but I was using Capital letters to start a state name (**A**labama) and it didn't work. Once I changed to small letteres (**a**labama) it worked.